# Getting error with deployed Serverless Flask app on AWS, No module named 'werkzeug._compat'

Tags: python, flask, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, werkzeug

I have created a simple Flask app and successfully deployed it to AWS Lambda.  I am following the first steps of [this tutorial](https://www.serverless.com/blog/flask-python-rest-api-serverless-lambda-dynamodb).

When the Lambda is run, the following error appears in the log:

```
Unable to import module 'wsgi_handler': No module named 'werkzeug._compat'
```

I have installed serverless-python-requirements and serverless-wsgi.  The folders are present in the zip folder that was uploaded to AWS.

I found the reference to werkzeug._compat in serverless_wsgi.py:

```
from werkzeug._compat import BytesIO, string_types, to_bytes, wsgi_encoding_dance
```

However, I cannot seem to find "_compat" anywhere in the Werkzeug folder where this function might be found.  Am I missing a package or something?

Here is my serverless.yml:

```
# serverless.yml

service: serverless-flask

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
  - serverless-wsgi

custom:
  wsgi:
    app: app.app
    packRequirements: false
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1

functions:
  app:
    handler: wsgi_handler.handler
    events:
      - http: ANY /
      - http: 'ANY {proxy+}'
```

And my requirements.txt:

```
click==8.0.0
dataclasses==0.8
Flask==2.0.0
itsdangerous==2.0.0
Jinja2==3.0.0
MarkupSafe==2.0.0
Werkzeug==2.0.0
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Flask, Werkzeug and other pallets projects just had a major update, dropping python2 support and deleting `_compat` module. And AWS has't resolve the capability issue yet.

The simplest fix will be downgrading Flask, Werkzeug, etc. to the previous major version.

Comment: This saved us hours! We downgraded to `Flask 1.1.4` and resolved the issue. Cheers!

Comment: WoW same, this saved hours! Thanks

Comment: For anybody else facing this, I also had to downgrade to `Werkzeug==1.0.1` in order to get this working.

Comment: Is there any supporting documentation for this?  How would we know when AWS changed its runtimes appropriately?

Comment: @AnatoliyKats I am not using AWS as serverless service provider, but after reading the tutorial in the question I found the relevant [code](https://github.com/logandk/serverless-wsgi/blob/b362524301a7da6ee7a64462051eee07bb7c8e2f/serverless_wsgi.py#L18) and [issue](https://github.com/logandk/serverless-wsgi/issues/179). I am using Tencent and [here](https://github.com/serverless-components/tencent-flask/blob/75d5f466c293c315837d49523ed1854f661ac0e0/src/_shims/severless_wsgi.py#L17) is the code.